# SqlDependency event not firing

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, service-broker

many people seem to have problem in making this work, so i am not new to here, hoping someone would be able to point out what else i can check, this is what i am doing...

Environment : .net 4.0, **SQL Server Exrpress 2008 R2**

**Steps taken to setup the database**

```
CREATE QUEUE WebSiteCacheMessages ;

CREATE SERVICE WebCacheNotifications ON QUEUE WebSiteCacheMessages
  ([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification]) ;
CREATE ROUTE WebCacheMessagesRoute WITH SERVICE_NAME = 'WebCacheNotifications',ADDRESS = 'LOCAL' ;

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', '1'
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

ALTER DATABASE EFTest SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO     
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[EFTEST] TO [domain\user];
GO
```

Following code to test the notification

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var id = 0;
            string sqlStatement = "SELECT [Id] ,[FirstName],[LastName],[Email] FROM [dbo].[People]";
            string queueName = "WebSiteCacheMessages";
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDataContext"].ConnectionString;
            try
            {

                SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, queueName);
                using (var db = new DataContext(connectionString))
                {
                    var person = new Person { Email = "test@test.com", FirstName = "Testy", LastName = "Tester", HomeAddress = address };
                    db.Persons.Add(person);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    id = person.Id;
                }
                var dependency = new SqlDependency();
                dependency.AddCommandDependency(new SqlCommand(sqlStatement));
                dependency.OnChange += (o, e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Notification called !");
                };
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            finally
            {
                SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString, queueName);
            }
        }
```

when i run an update statement on the email column in query window on sql server, i dont see on change event being fired.

There are no events in the event log or database logs, and when i run the following query, i dont see anything

```
select * from WebSiteCacheMessages -- queue name
select * from sys.transmission_queue
```

many thanks for reading through this...

Comment: The Docs have : Users who execute commands requesting notification must have SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS database permission on the server. - is that being performed in a piece of script not included?

Comment: When i run following commands GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO [domain\user]
GO
GRANT SEND on service::WebCacheNotifications to [domain\user] GO i get Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.

Comment: You don't need to drop to single user to enable broker. Simply run `ALTER DATABASE EFTest SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`.

Comment: recreated the database from scratch, ran the whole procedure again, still no luck :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually execute any command with a SqlDependency on it. You simply associate the SqlDependency with a SqlCommand, but you don't actually **execute** the SqlCommand. The Query Notification on server gets created only when you execute the SQL statement. Something like:

```
var dependency = new SqlDependency();
var SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement);
dependency.AddCommandDependency(cmd);
dependency.OnChange += (o, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Notification called !");
};

// Executing the command will submit the query notification request
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader ()) {
   while (rdr.Reader ()) {
      ...
   }
}
Console.Reade ();
```

Another alternative is to use [LinqToCache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/) and query your `DataContext.Persons`:

```
var people = from p in db.Persons select new {p.Id, p.LastName, p.FirstName, p.Email};
var peopleCached = people.AsCached("Persons", new QueryCachedOptions () {
  OnInvalidate = (sender, args) => {
    Console.WriteLine("Notification called !");
  }
 });
// Again, the underlying SqlCommand must actually be executed. Iterate the query
foreach (p in peopleCached ) {
 ....
}
```

Comment: I am executing the command but SqlDependency OnChange is not called when database table updated from SQL Server Management Studio or from other instance of the application. Though I am not getting any error but OnChange is not firing, I have checked Transmission Queue and it is empty all the time. Why?

Comment: foreach (p in peopleCached ) {
 ....
}        FOR THIS FOREACH STATEMENT. WHAT WOULD BE INSIDE THIS LOOP??